# How do I log in as a 'test user' for in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, testing, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have implemented all of the purchases and created the test user accounts - yet when I come to test; it says that I need to be signed in as a test user, obviously. The problem is I'm not sure how to log in as my 'test account' as the it's not an official account technically. I'm unsure of where I need to go to get access to the test user?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App-Store test account login settings; not specific code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @shabzco said you should log out with Settings --> iTunes & App Stores --> Logout.

However, you should *not* log in again using this page with your test account or iTunes will ask you to 'verify payment information' which you can't do as it's a test account.

Instead, run your app, make your test purchase and when the IAP popup appears enter your test user details.

Note the popup will say 'Environment: Sandbox' which indicates that it's a test purchase and no-one will be charged.

Comment: my mistake, I'll remove my answer and vote yours up :)